# Change mobile menu breakpoint - WordPress Twenty-Twenty-Three theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, media-queries

**WordPress Navigation Block - Twenty-Twenty-Three theme**

How to change the CSS media-query breakpoint at which the hamburger button displays on mobile and the full menu on wider screens?

---

*The hamburger minimize-able menu can be turned on from* *Dashboard->Appearance->Editor*:

[image: Appearance->Editor]

Answer (score 2):

add this to your child theme's CSS changing the value in the parenthesis:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* hamburger button */
  .wp-block-navigation__responsive-container-open  {
    display: block !important;
  }

  /* full menu */
  .wp-block-navigation__responsive-container:not(.is-menu-open.has-modal-open) {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to add, this works for all various site editing themes even custom ones.